# Wait for angular to finish updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, callback

I need to attach bootstrap datepicker to one of my input fields that will be generated with AngularJS.

Doing the following doesn't work because the element does not yet exist:

```
$(function () {
    $(':input[name=dispense_date]').datepicker();
});
```

Instead I must do:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $(':input[name=dispense_date]').datepicker();
    }, 200);
});
```

The latter version works but is inefficient and not exactly the "correct" way to do this. Do angular controllers/modules have a method for running callbacks after everything completes?

I need the jquery code to run after an $http.get() call, but simply adding it inside the .success() call won't do the trick since $apply hasn't ran yet.

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel.  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: True, but I didn't like the look of their datepicker.

Answer (score 8):

Use $timeout:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $(':input[name=dispense_date]').datepicker();
});
```

Angular will ensure that the timeout function executes after the compile/link phase and even after the render phase.

Comment: pixelbits, Is there a version of $timeout that runs after $http.success() has ran?

Comment: @ramin - no I'm pretty sure there is not. That being said, $timeout returns a promise so you can easily chain the $timeout to run after your $http call (which also returns a promise)

Comment: You can put the $timeout call within the success handler - it may trigger another digest but that is core to the way angular works.  You probably don't need two chained promises - you'll manipulate models in your success handler, then you might want to call $timeout in the success handler to re initialize your datepicker

Comment: Suppose I change a data (which is bind in the view). Is it possible to wait for angular to render and then do something?