# Selenium: how to wait for AngularJS to finish updating the DOM after AJAX?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, selenium, asynchronous

[Related philosophical debate about just sleeping it out at [programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/294059/44660)]

Angualr is not guaranteed to update the DOM completely in the event handler for the AJAX completion (especially if third-party directives are involved), so most of the solutions floating online about using `$http interceptors` are incomplete.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24792190/499922) to a very similar question "Wait for angular to finish updating the DOM", suggests using `$timeout`. However, its [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/timeout.js) suggests it uses the `$browser.defer` mechanism so can actually be executed in any order with other deferred DOM manipulation.

I found [`$browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/browser.js#L75) internal method which happens after all the `deferred` stuff, but the test is still unstable after waiting for that. I guess I should wait for AJAX to complete first or is there something else I've missed?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711556/how-to-impact-the-html-rendering-priorities-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments, it seems `notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests` is sufficient.

(Previously, my test code created a new `Injector` to get the `$browser` service, which is actually different from the one used by the application. I switched to the ["proper" one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508731/499922) and it worked.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it:

```
function waitForDisplayed(element) {
   var d = protractor.promise.defer(); // the result of this being fulfilled is returned
   browser.wait(element.isDisplayed).
      then(function(isDisplayed) {
         d.fulfill();
      });
      return d.promise;
}
```

Comment: What if the element is already in the DOM and I am waiting for its value to change?